# Weak flat condition?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a unit ring (not necessarily commutative). Then it is clear that for a right $R$-module $M$ we have:

$M$ is flat $R$-module $\Rightarrow$ for any left $R$-module $E$ with $E\otimes_{R}M=0$ and any submodule $E'\leq E$, we have $E'\otimes_{R}M=0$.

> Can anyone give me a counterexample to show the inverse implication is not correct?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $M$ seems to be a left module and $E$ a right module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M=R\oplus T$ where $T$ is not flat. Then $M\otimes E=E\oplus (T\otimes E)$ which is 0, if and only if $E=0$.

Comment: $M$ is not a flat $R$-module, this is clear, but you have to verify for all possible modules $E$, the right hand side condition is satisfied for $M$, not a special $E$.

Comment: Impressing! Very clever idea! You can put it as an answer so that I could accept it. Thanks!